# ¿Cómo hacer una tabla de distribución de frecuencias con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, frecuencia

Estoy trabajando con distribuciones de frecuencias, hice un script sencillo pero muy redundante que me permite obtener la distribución de frecuencias relativa de ciertos datos, pero no creo que sea la mejor implementación, busque por la red pero no encontré mucho acerca de como hacer estas tablas (no así de histogramas de frecuencia)

Mi idea general es esta:

> mujeres.txt

```
76 
72
88 
60 
72 
68 
80 
64 
68 
68 
80 
76 
68 
72 
96 
72 
68 
72 
64 
80
64 
80 
76 
76 
76 
80 
104 
88 
60 
76 
72 
72 
88 
80 
60 
72 
88 
88 
124 
64
```

> codigo.py

```
import numpy as np
from math import ceil

datos = np.genfromtxt('mujeres.txt')

def distribucion_frecuencias_relativas(datos, numero_clases):

    anchura_clase = (max(datos) - min(datos)) / numero_clases # anchura de clase = (valor más alto) - (valor más bajo) / numero de clases
    anchura_clase = ceil(anchura_clase)
    clases = [] # ejemplo: clases[[inferior, superior]]
    limite_inferior = min(datos)
    limite_superior = anchura_clase - 1
    frecuencia = []

    for i in range(numero_clases):
        if len(clases) == 0:
            clases.append([limite_inferior, (limite_inferior + limite_superior)])
        else:
            limite_inferior += anchura_clase
            clases.append([limite_inferior, (limite_inferior + limite_superior)])
        frecuencia.append([])

    for valor in datos:
        for i in range(0, numero_clases):
            if valor >= clases[i][0] and valor <= clases[i][1]:
                frecuencia[i].append(valor)
                break   

    print(" Pulso\t\t", "Frecuencia")
    for i in range(0, numero_clases):
        print("{0}-{1}\t {2:.1f}%".format(clases[i][0], clases[i][1], ((len(frecuencia[i]) / len(datos)) * 100) ))
```

¿Cómo podría simplificar esto y hacerlo de la manera correcta y más pythonica? quise hacerlo implementando un poco más de numpy pero al final no lo hice por no saber como comparar los datos con los rangos de las clases. También intente con pandas, pero no supe como generar los limites de cada clase.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Numpy** es una librería que contiene una gran cantidad de funciones de cálculo númerico, por lo que usted busca ya esta implementada.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "mujeres.txt"
data = np.loadtxt(filename)
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, 10)
plt.hist(data, bins=bin_edges)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si precisamente con el histograma no tenia problemas, me preguntaba por la tabla, pero creo que esto será mucho mejor, gracias.

Comment: Ya estuve jugando con los valores y revise la documentación de `np.histogram` ya pude construir la tabla, gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que se desea es solamente crear una tabla de frecuencias, se puede hacer:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Crear un array numpy
data = np.array([[2, 6, 4, 8], [10, 5, 2, 6], [8, 4, 6, 2], 
                 [6, 2, 5, 8], [5, 4, 14, 2] ])
# Crear un dataframe con un  numpy array
datos_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': data[:, 0], 'Column2': data[:, 1], 'Column3': data[:, 2], 'Column4': data[:, 3] })
# Deuelve una lista por cada fila
lista_variables = datos_1.values.tolist()
# Ordenación de los datos.
lista_ordenada_variables = np.sort(lista_variables, axis=None)
frecuencias = pd.Series(lista_ordenada_variables).value_counts()
print ("\nVariable (X) - Frecuencias absolutas (f)\n" ,dicc(frecuencias))
```

No obstante aprecio que tu proyecto es más ambicioso pues ¿quizás pretendes establecer también clases y marcas de clase?.
En este caso, deberias modificar el título.

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción, utilizando la "lista_ordenada_variables" anteriormente mencionada:

```
df =np.array(lista_ordenada_variables)
df1 = pd.value_counts(df).to_frame().reset_index()
df1.rename(columns={"index":"Variable_X",0:"frecuencia_f"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que queremos es crear intervalos de clase, conocidos el límite inferior del primer intervalo y el tamaño c =  6 de cada intervalo de clase, podemos hacer

```
datos = np.zeros((6, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns = ["LimInf", "LimSup"] )

df.iloc[0,0] = 13
c = 6
df.iloc[0, 1] = 13 + c -1
for i in range (1, df.shape[0]):
    df.iloc[i,0] = df.iloc[i-1,1] + 1
    df.iloc[i, 1] = df.iloc[i,0] + c -1
df
```

Nos retorna

```
    LimInf  LimSup
0   13.0    18.0
1   19.0    24.0
2   25.0    30.0
3   31.0    36.0
4   37.0    42.0
5   43.0    48.0
```

Answer (score 0):

La marca de clase la podemos añadir en una columna

```
df["MarcaClase"] = (df["LimSup"] + df["LimInf"]) / 2
df
```

Nos devuelve

```
    LimInf  LimSup  MarcaClase
0   13  18  15.5
1   19  24  21.5
2   25  30  27.5
3   31  36  33.5
4   37  42  39.5
5   43  48  45.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Si buscas en esta Web "Intervalos de clase y frecuencia absoluta", encontraras la siguiente solución al problema.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math


data = np.array(
    [[15, 38, 14, 13, 29, 25], [20, 13, 16, 32, 44, 39],
     [45, 46, 19, 23, 24, 18], [19, 20, 21, 18, 25, 33],
     [13, 18, 22, 24, 27, 27]]
    )

pd.set_option('precision', 2)
datos = data[:,:].flatten()


k = 1 + 3.322 * math.log10(len(datos))
periodos = math.ceil(k)

inf = datos.min()        # Limite inferior del primer intervalo
dif = datos.max()
sup = datos.max() + 1    # Limite superior del último intervalo

intervals = pd.interval_range(
    start=inf,
    end=sup,
    periods=k,
    name="Intervalo",
    closed="left")

df = pd.DataFrame(index=intervals)
df["FreqAbs"] = pd.cut(datos, bins=df.index).value_counts()
df["Marca"]  = df.index.mid

df["LimInf"] = df.index.left
df["LimSup"] = df.index.right
df
```

Que devuelve:

```
    FreqAbs     Marca   LimInf  LimSup
Intervalo               
[13.0, 19.8)    11  16.4    13.0    19.8
[19.8, 26.6)    9   23.2    19.8    26.6
[26.6, 33.4)    5   30.0    26.6    33.4
[33.4, 40.2)    2   36.8    33.4    40.2
[40.2, 47.0)    3   43.6    40.2    47.0
```

En dicha página encontrarás más explicaciones.